# How to sort a binding source with joins?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ado.net

I have a table called Tenants, and it has a field called PropertyID and UnitID.

I also have a binding source for this table (Tenants), however I want it sort it, but the values I want to sort it by are not in the table itself.

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT t.*, p.PropertyName, u.UnitNumber FROM Tenants t
LEFT JOIN Properties p ON t.PropertyID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN Units u ON t.UnitID = u.ID
ORDER BY p.PropertyName, u.UnitNumber
```

How can I do this with the binding source?

Comment: may be i'm not fully understand problem, but I think Linq to Object may solve this problem

Comment: The datasource is the Tenant table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a view with this query, and bind to that.